# C++: eccentricity function on metric spaces

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented

An eccentricity function with parameter \$r\$ on a metric space \$X\$ with \$N\$ points is

\begin{gather}
f(y) = \left( \sum_{x \in X} \frac {d^r(x, y)}  N \right)^{1/r};~~~x,y \in X
\end{gather}
(Note: for the implementation \$X\$ is a finite metric space since \$N<\infty\$ for computability)

I have tried to implement this for a general `MetricSpace` class, with two example metric spaces, namely \$\mathbb{R}^n\$ and a metric on DNA strands. However, as currently implemented I cannot declare the eccentricity function as a friend of `MetricSpace` because `MetricSpace` is a template. So I had to make two eccentricity functions, one for \$\mathbb{R}^n\$ and one for DNA. This approach works but is not ideal.

How can I improve the design of the program for maintainability so it becomes possible to define just one eccentricity function that takes a `MetricSpace` as argument, which can then either be `Rn` or `DNA`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

template<typename T>
class MetricSpace {
public:
    double d();

private:
    std::vector<T> points_;
};

class Rn : public MetricSpace<std::vector<double>> {
public:
    using MetricSpace::d; // So we can overload the distance function

    // Constructor
    Rn(std::vector<std::vector<double>> points, int n): dimension_{n} {
        points_ = points;

        bool invalidDimension = false;
        for (long i = 0; i < points_.size(); i++) {
            if (points_[i].size() != dimension_) {
                invalidDimension = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (invalidDimension) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("At least one point has the wrong dimension.");
        }
    }

    // Distance function
    double d(const std::vector<double>& point1, const std::vector<double>& point2) {
        double squaredDistance{0};

        for (int i = 0; i < dimension_; i++) {
            squaredDistance += (point1[i] - point2[i])*(point1[i] - point2[i]);
        }

        return sqrt(squaredDistance);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> points_;
    int dimension_;
    friend double eccentric(Rn& space, long pointIndex, double r);
};

// Elements are sequences finite (x_1, ..., x_N) with x_i in {A, C, G, T}
// and the distance d(x, y) is the amount of i for which x_i != y_i.
class DNA: public MetricSpace<std::vector<char>> {
public:
    using MetricSpace::d;

    // Constructor
    DNA(std::vector<std::vector<char>> points, int length): length_{length} {
        points_ = points;

        bool invalidDimension = false;
        bool invalidCharacter = false;

        for (long i = 0; i < points_.size(); i++) {
            if (points_[i].size() != length_) {
                invalidDimension = true;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < points_[i].size(); j++) {
                if ( points_[i][j] != 'A' && points_[i][j] != 'C' && points_[i][j] != 'G' && points_[i][j] != 'T' ) {
                    invalidCharacter = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (invalidDimension) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("At least one DNA strand is too long or too short.");
        }

        if (invalidCharacter) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("At least one DNA strand contains a character not equal to A, C, G or T.");
        }

    }

    // Distance function
    double d(const std::vector<char>& point1, const std::vector<char>& point2) {
        int counter{0};
        for (int i = 0; i < point1.size(); i++) {
            if (point1[i] != point2[i]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return counter;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> points_;
    int length_;
    friend double eccentric2(DNA& space, long pointIndex, double r);
};


double eccentric(Rn& space, long pointIndex, double r) {
    double sum = 0;
    long N = space.points_.size();
    for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += pow(space.d(space.points_[pointIndex], space.points_[i]), r);
    }

    return pow(sum/N, 1/r);
}

double eccentric2(DNA& space, long pointIndex, double r) {
    double sum = 0;
    long N = space.points_.size();
    for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += pow(space.d(space.points_[pointIndex], space.points_[i]), r);
    }

    return pow(sum/N, 1/r);
}

Rn RnMaker(int dimension, long numberOfPoints) {

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> points;

    // Setting up the random machine
    double lowerBound = 0;
    double upperBound = 10;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform(lowerBound, upperBound);
    std::default_random_engine randomEngine;

    // Creating the random points
    for (long i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
        std::vector<double> point;
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            point.push_back(uniform(randomEngine));
        }
        points.push_back(point);
    }

    return Rn(points, dimension);
}

DNA DNAMaker(int length, long numberOfPoints) {

    std::vector<std::vector<char>> points;

    // Random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    char characters[4] = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};

    // Creating the random points
    for (long i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
        std::vector<char> point;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            point.push_back(characters[rand() % 4]);
        }
        points.push_back(point);
    }

    return DNA(points, length);
}

int main() {
    Rn space = RnMaker(3, 100);
    DNA space2 = DNAMaker(10, 100);

    std::cout << "Eccentricity of the 10'th point in R^n with r = 2.1: " << eccentric(space, 10, 2.1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Eccentricity of the 10'th point in a DNA metric space with r = 2.1: " << eccentric2(space2, 10, 2.1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: _How do I [do x]_ is generally off-topic for this site. If you're asking for general feedback on maintainability, including how to improve flexibility of your eccentricity function, you may want to modify your wording a little. Your code as it stands works now, yes?

Comment: It works as it stands now. I'll reword it.

Comment: I can't edit it, even when I literally do not change anything it tells me there is improperly formatted code. Please review the on topic parts if you want to, and I'll ask the rest somewhere else.

Comment: I think it's generally on-topic. I'm going to venture a guess at an edit; please tell me if it's what you had in mind.

Comment: @Reinderien That is exactly what I had in mind, thanks!

Comment: Btw the improper formatting is likely due to the fact that your triple-backtick was unterminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use a template for the inner type
- Make the base abstract
- Use `const` references where appropriate
- Move the definition of your character list to the class
- Convert the "make" methods to constructors
- Use `std::find` instead of an inner loop in your validation code
- Use `std::array` to force a square matrix rather than needing to loop through
- Only write one definition of `eccentric`
- Do not store the dimension number as a member

Suggested:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>


template<
    size_t N,    // The point size
    typename T,  // The array sub-type
    typename D   // The distance type
>
class MetricSpace {
public:
    typedef std::array<T, N> Point;

    virtual D distance(
        const Point &point1,
        const Point &point2
    ) const = 0;

    // Note that this always returns a promoted double and not the distance type
    double eccentric(size_t pointIndex, double r) const {
        double sum = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0, e = points.size(); i != e; i++) {
            // Skip computation of the distance to "self" which should be 0
            if (i != pointIndex) {
                D dist = distance(points[pointIndex], points[i]);
                sum += pow(dist, r);
            }
        }

        return pow(sum/points.size(), 1/r);
    }

protected:
    MetricSpace() {}
    MetricSpace(const std::vector<Point> &_points) : points(_points) {}

    std::vector<Point> points;
};


template<
    size_t N,
    typename T = double,
    typename D = double
>
class Rn: public MetricSpace<N, T, D> {
public:
    typedef MetricSpace<N, T, D> Base;
    typedef typename Base::Point Point;

    Rn(const std::vector<Point> &_points): Base(_points) {}

    Rn(size_t n_points) {
        // Setting up the random machine
        T lowerBound = 0, upperBound = 10;
        std::uniform_real_distribution<T> uniform(lowerBound, upperBound);
        std::default_random_engine randomEngine;

        // Creating the random points
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n_points; i++) {
            Point point;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                point[j] = uniform(randomEngine);
            }
            Base::points.push_back(point);
        }
    }

    D distance(const Point &point1, const Point &point2) const {
        D squaredDistance = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0, e = point1.size(); i != e; i++) {
            T diff = point1[i] - point2[i];
            squaredDistance += diff*diff;
        }

        return sqrt(squaredDistance);
    }
};


// Elements are sequences finite (x_1, ..., x_N) with x_i in {A, C, G, T}
// and the distance d(x, y) is the amount of i for which x_i != y_i.
template<
    size_t N,
    typename T = char,
    typename D = int
>
class DNA: public MetricSpace<N, T, D> {
public:
    typedef MetricSpace<N, T, D> Base;
    typedef typename Base::Point Point;

    DNA(const std::vector<Point> &_points): Base(_points) {
        validate();
    }

    DNA(size_t n_points) {
        // Random seed
        srand(time(NULL));

        // Creating the random points
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n_points; i++) {
            Point point;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                point[j] = characters[rand() % 4];
            }
            Base::points.push_back(point);
        }

        validate();
    }

    void validate() const {
        const char *last = characters + sizeof(characters);
        for (const Point &p: Base::points) {
            for (T x: p) {
                if (std::find(characters, last, x) == last) {
                    throw std::invalid_argument(
                        std::string("At least one DNA strand contains bad character '")
                        + x + '\''
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    D distance(const Point &point1, const Point &point2) const {
        D counter = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < point1.size(); i++) {
            if (point1[i] != point2[i]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return counter;
    }

    static constexpr T characters[] = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};
};


int main() {
    Rn<3> space = Rn<3>(100);
    DNA<10> space2 = DNA<10>(100);

    std::cout << "Eccentricity of the 10'th point in R^n with r = 2.1: "
              << space.eccentric(10, 2.1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Eccentricity of the 10'th point in a DNA metric space with r = 2.1: "
              << space2.eccentric(10, 2.1) << std::endl;
}
```

Caveat: "some" of this is modern C++, though I'm not an expert. This compiles and runs with `g++ -Wall -std=c++17`.

Answer (score 5):

## Be consistent

There are many inconsistencies in your code:

- Why is there a `MetricSpace::d()` that takes no parameters?
- Why use proper C++ random functions in `RnMaker()`, but `srand()`/`rand()` in `DNAMaker()`?
- Why use a templated base class for `MetricSpace`, but then have specialized `eccentric()` function?

## Turn on compiler warnings and fix them

My compiler warns about your use of `long i` in `for`-loops, where you compare it against a `size_t` value from for example `points_.size()`. Again, be consistent, and use `size_t` consistently for all sizes, counts and indices.

## Remove `class MetricSpace`

Nothing in it is actually used by the derived classes, everything is overridden. You can remove this class and your code will still compile and work.

## Make `eccentric()` a template

Both `eccentric()` and `eccentric2()` do exactly the same thing, only the type of the first parameter is different. That's a job for templates. So:

```
template<typename Space>
double eccentric(Space& space, size_t pointIndex, double r) {
    ...
}
```

You also need to update your `friend` declarations to match the template:

```
class Rn {
    ...
    template<typename Space>
    friend double eccentric(Space& space, size_t pointIndex, double r);
};
```

## Consider allowing `const` access to `points_`

Instead of making `points_` `private` and needing to add `friend` declarations for whatever function needs to access `points_`, consider adding an accessor function to get a `const` reference to `points_`, like so:

```
class Rn {
public:
    ...
    const auto &get_points() const {
        return points_;
    }
    ...
};
```

(Note that this relies on C++14, for earlier versions you need to specify the return type explicitly.) Then in `eccentric()` you can write:

```
template<typename Space>
double eccentric(Space& space, size_t pointIndex, double r) {
    auto &points = space.get_points();
    size_t N = points.size();
    ...
}
```

## Consider making the dimension/length of a point a template parameter

A vector of vectors is very inefficient. And for a given space, all points in that space have the same dimension or length. So it makes sense to make that a template parameter, and then use a `std::array` for each point. While you are at it, use a `using`-declaration to declare the type of a point to save some typing. For example:

```
template<size_t Dimension>
class Rn {
public:
    using Point = std::array<double, Dimension>;
    
    Rn(const std::vector<Point> &points): points_(points) {}

    double d(const Point &point1, const Point &point2) {
        ...
    }        
    
private:
    std::vector<Point> points_;
};
```

You also have to make `RnMaker()` a template, such that in `main()` you write something like:

```
auto space = RnMaker<3>(100);
```

## Make the `Maker()` functions static member functions

This avoids all the issues you have above with making `RnMaker()` and `DNAMaker()` templates and friends. By making them static member functions, they are already part of the template, and they can access private member variables without issues. For example:

```
template <size_t Dimension>
class Rn {
public:
    using Point = std::array<double, Dimension>;

    Rn(const std::vector<Point> &points = {}): points_(points) {}

    double d(const Point& point1, const Point& point2) {
        ...
    }

    static Rn generate(size_t numberOfPoints) {
        Rn space;
        ...
        // Creating the random points
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
            Point point;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < Dimension; j++) {
                 point[j] = uniform(randomEngine);
             }
             space.points_.push_back(point);
         }

        return space;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Point> points_;
};
```

And then you use it like so:

```
auto space = Rn<3>::generate(100);
```

You can do something similar for `DNA` of course.

## Consider using STL algorithms

There are several STL algorithms that can help you replace some of the manual `for`-loops you have, for example [`std::generate_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) to fill `points_` with random points, and [`std::inner_product()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) to calculate the sum of distances raised to a power.

## Use `std::pow()` and `std::sqrt()`

While it is not an issue in your code, you should prefer using the `std::` variant of math functions whereever possible. These will have overloads for the floating point and possibly integer types, and so will be more efficient and/or correct than the C math functions `pow()` and `sqrt()` with always assume `double`, and would implicitly cast.

## Naming things

I would rename `eccentric()` to `eccentricity()` or perhaps even `calculate_eccentricity()`. Prefer using verbs for functions and nouns for most other things.

Also consider renaming `d()` to `distance()`. I know the former is a common abbreviation in mathematics, but it is less common in programming.

Comment: "Maker" functions being static is "fine" - and in fact that would be the only option in Python. In C++ there's constructor overloading, so there's no reason for them not to be constructors.

Comment: @Reinderien: True, although I wouldn't make a constructor that fills itself with random points just for testing. The original function was maybe better in that regard, except for the vector being copied. Maybe a constructor that takes an r-value reference to a vector of points then, so it can be efficiently moved, and then still an external function that generates the random points?

Comment: Yeah that would be reasonable. Honestly I don't understand the scientific background, so if the use of random is for technical purposes it's safe in a constructor, but if it's just for a "demo" then yes, perhaps separated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I have a question about the vector of vectors: a point in a metric space will not generally be a vector of some fixed length like in these examples (so perhaps poorly chosen examples). For example DNA strands could have different lengths, or we could have a metric space of functions. 

If I make MetricSpace abstract, with the points an array of type T with a template, is there a better choice than yet another std::array when implementing Rn and DNA?

Comment: If a point really has a variable length, then using a `std::vector` instead of a `std::array` for it is of course fine. Use the best type for the points in the metric space.